# Vertical divs with divisions

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page on my site with X vertical divisions. These span from the top to the bottom of the page and take up, say 10vw.

This is fine, however what I am struggling with now is that INSIDE those vertical divs I want sections. Some of the vertical divs will have 1 section, some 2, and some three.

[This is a fiddle of what I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/48tvezgv/)

```css
#topics_selection-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 27px;
  bottom: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.topics_selection-level_container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 99.5%;
  width: 10vw;
  margin: 0px -5px 0px 0px;
  overflow: none;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_1 {
  background: green;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_2 {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_3 {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_4 {
  background: magenta;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_5 {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_6 {
  background: purple;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33%;
}

.topics_selection-level_1 {
  background: red;
}

.topics_selection-level_2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="topics_selection-container">
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_1">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_2"></div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_4"></div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_5"></div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as you SEE it works! Thats exactly what I want (except for the small space at the bottom of the three because of the 33%). However when I put content into those smaller divisions you get something different happening. The kind of wrap to the size of the text.

Can anybody suggest how to fix this? Positioning is CSS is not my forte!

Comment: set `vertical-align: top;` to the inner cells...

Comment: use `height: calc(100% / 3);` instead of `height: 33%;` and `vertical-algin:top` to `topics_selection-level_container`

Comment: set a width for the inner cells or else a float.

Comment: @fcalderan not inner cells but their container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flex for this then the level 2 divs can just grow to fit the column:

```css
#topics_selection-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 27px;
  bottom: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: none;
  
  display: flex;           
  flex-direction: row; /* align level 1 children in columns */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topics_selection-level_container {
  height: 99.5%;
  width: 10vw;
  margin: 0px;      /* not sure what your left margin was doing so removed it - you can add it back if you want */
  overflow: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  /* align level 2 children in rows within this column */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.topics_selection-level_container > div {
  flex:1;                /* make level2 children grow to fill the column equally */
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;   /* this is for vertical aligning */
  
  justify-content: center; /* these 2 are for horizontal aligning */
  text-align:center;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_1 {
  background: green;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_2 {
  background: gray;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_3 {
  background: blue;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_4 {
  background: magenta;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_5 {
  background: orange;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_6 {
  background: purple;
}

.topics_selection-level_1 {
  background: red;
}

.topics_selection-level_2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="topics_selection-container">

  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_1">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_1">add</div>
  </div>

  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_2">stuff may be over multiple lines</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_3">stuff</div>
  </div>

  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_4">stuff that can wrap</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_5">this works</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_6">yeah!</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I didnt know about flex thanks for the insight. Do you know how I would further vertically align within the flex boxes? I have been trying 'justify-content: center;' in any of the boxes to no avail. Should this be the only padding trick?

Comment: @AlexanderBunting See the above edit - you need to make the level 2 div flex and put the aligning on that

Comment: I had tried the justifications but hadn't made it flex! Thanks Pete :)

Answer (score 3):

Change `overflow: none;` into `overflow: hidden;` in `.topics_selection-level_container`. That will do the trick.

```
.topics_selection-level_container { display: inline-block; height: 99.5%; width: 10vw; margin: 0px -5px 0px 0px; overflow: hidden; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/48tvezgv/4/

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to floats, it'll work.

```
.topics_selection-level_container { float:left; height: 99.5%; width: 10vw; margin: 0;  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/48tvezgv/3/

```css
#topics_selection-container { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 27px; bottom: 20px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; }

.topics_selection-level_container { float:left; height: 99.5%; width: 10vw; margin: 0;  }

.topics_selection-split_cell_1 { background: green; margin: 0px; height: 100%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_2 { background: gray; margin: 0px; height: 50%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_3 { background: blue; margin: 0px; height: 50%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_4 { background: magenta; margin: 0px; height: calc(100% / 3); }
.topics_selection-split_cell_5 { background: orange; margin: 0px; height: calc(100% / 3); }
.topics_selection-split_cell_6 { background: purple; margin: 0px; height: calc(100% / 3); }

.topics_selection-level_1 { background: red; }
.topics_selection-level_2 { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="topics_selection-container">

  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_1">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_1">zxczxc</div>
  </div>
         
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_2">asdas</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_3">qweqwe</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_4">cvbcvb</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_5">urtyryr</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_6">hdhdfh</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Also "none" is not a valid value for overflow, I think you want to use hidden. And 33% is not precise enough, use `calc (100% / 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `height:33.333333%` instead of 33% as `33*3=99`...so your 1% is remaining...

You have applied `display:inline-block` to the outer containers which has by default `vertical-align:baseline`...

You have to change it to `vertical-align:top`

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48tvezgv/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#topics_selection-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 27px;
  bottom: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.topics_selection-level_container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 99.5%;
  width: 10vw;
  margin: 0px -5px 0px 0px;
  overflow: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_1 {
  background: green;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_2 {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_3 {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_4 {
  background: magenta;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33.333333%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_5 {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33.333333%;
}

.topics_selection-split_cell_6 {
  background: purple;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 33.333333%;
}

.topics_selection-level_1 {
  background: red;
}

.topics_selection-level_2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="topics_selection-container">
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_1">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_2"></div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_4">ggg</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_5">ffff</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_6">dddd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adjust the height a little you can give one 34% or give them all 33% with more decimal points.

EDIT: Added content to each inner div and align elements to top of parents.

```css
#topics_selection-container { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 27px; display:inline-block; bottom: 20px; overflow-x: auto; vertical-align:top; overflow-y: none; white-space: nowrap; }
.topics_selection-level_container { display: inline-block; height: 99.5%; width: 10vw; margin: 0px -5px 0px 0px; overflow: none; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_1 { background: green; margin: 0px; height: 100%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_2 { background: gray; margin: 0px; height: 50%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_3 { background: blue; margin: 0px; height: 50%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_4 { background: magenta; margin: 0px;  height: 34%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_5 { background: orange; margin: 0px;   height: 33%; }
.topics_selection-split_cell_6 { background: purple; margin: 0px; height: 33%; }
.topics_selection-level_1 { background: red; vertical-align:top; }
.topics_selection-level_2 { background: yellow; vertical-align:top; }
```

```html
<div id="topics_selection-container">

  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_1">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_1">asdf</div>
  </div>
         
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_2">asdf</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_3">asdf</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="topics_selection-level_container topics_selection-level_2">
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_4">asdf</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_5">asdf</div>
    <div class="topics_selection-split_cell_6">asdf</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: but this is not the main issue ... read the end of the question. By the way i don't agree to do this as you can use calc(100% / 3) and you will get a perfect division

Comment: add content to inner cells to see the issue